# Notation to count tuples

Tags: notation, multisets

I have the following set:
V={(0,0),(1,2),(1,3),(2,2),(3,2)}

I need to count tuples containing x = 1.

Can I use |V_{(1,y)}| ?

Or I should use |{(x,y) \in V | x = 1}| ?

Thanks,
Luiz

Comment: As this seems to be about notation only, you can do whatever you want as long as you inform your readership about your notations - $|\{ (x,y) \in V \mid x=1\}|$ is what one could call "standard notation" in this context.